# I'm using calrketm/TableExport , why xlsx button not showing up?

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel

i need to export html table data to xlsx. i am using calrketm/TableExport on github... but, i can't see Export to Xlsx button. What should i do? here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXaN4.jpg)

Comment: If you ever have any api or usage specific question, feel free to reach out to me directly via [github](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport) or take a peek at the [TableExport docs](https://www.travismclarke.com/tableexport/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because by default "xlsx" is not included. See the default below:

```
$("table").tableExport({
    headings: true,                     // (Boolean), display table headings (th/td elements) in the <thead>
    footers: true,                      // (Boolean), display table footers (th/td elements) in the <tfoot>
    formats: ["xls", "csv", "txt"],     // (String[]), filetype(s) for the export
    fileName: "id",                     // (id, String), filename for the downloaded file
    bootstrap: true,                    // (Boolean), style buttons using bootstrap
    position: "bottom",                 // (top, bottom), position of the caption element relative to table
    ignoreRows: null,                   // (Number, Number[]), row indices to exclude from the exported file
    ignoreCols: null,                   // (Number, Number[]), column indices to exclude from the exported file
    ignoreCSS: ".tableexport-ignore",   // (selector, selector[]), selector(s) to exclude cells from the exported file
    emptyCSS: ".tableexport-empty",     // (selector, selector[]), selector(s) to replace cells with an empty string in the exported file
    trimWhitespace: false               // (Boolean), remove all leading/trailing newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from cell text
});
```

To include "xlsx" you should supply the following config.

```
$("table").tableExport({
    formats: ["xls", "csv", "txt", "xlsx"]
});
```

Comment: i also need to include xlsx.core.js by SheetJS, it's working now. thanks.